# definition of simple group , why we need normal ???

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

Every prime ordered group is simple, its because it doesn't admit any subgroups. But where comes the normal subgroup, why cant the people use just subgroups instead of normal subgroups in the definition of simple group.
Does the normal subgroup has any influence when we are dealing with the structure of groups ???

In addition help me with an example of a group that admits subgroup but it doesn't have normal subgroups ???

Comment: Most simple groups do have subgroups.  For example, $A_5$ is simple, and contains many subgroups, such as $A_2, A_3, $ and $A_4$.

Comment: The point of the normal subgroups, by the way, is that the normal subgroups of a group $G$ are precisely those for which the quotient $G/N$ can be constructed.

Comment: I would say that normal subgroups are easily the single most important concept in group theory. Insisting that you omit studying them is like insisting that among all sets you only study the empty set.

Comment: help me with an example such that a group has a subgroup but it's not a normal subgroup.??

Comment: As I said three comments before, [$A_5$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alternating_group) is a simple group, but has many subgroups, which are therefore not normal.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you demand that "$G$ be a non-trivial group with no non-trivial subgroups." then you would be limiting yourself to **just** the groups of prime order (i.e. isomorphic to the integers mod a prime). This isn't very interesting.

[Quick sketch of a proof: Let $G$ be a non-trivial group of prime order. Then $G$ is cyclic and thus isomorphic to integers mod a prime. Otherwise, suppose $G$ is a non-trivial group of composite order. Suppose $p$ is a prime divisor of the group's order. [Cauchy's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%27s_theorem_%28group_theory%29) then states that $G$ has an element of order $p$ and thus has a non-trivial (proper) subgroup of order $p$. So all non-trivial groups of composite order have non-trivial proper subgroups.]

Also, being simple is all about not having "interesting" quotients. You can only quotient by **normal** subgroups.

A simple group is a non-trivial group whose quotients are just itself and the trivial group (up to isomorphism). This parallels the definition of a prime number whose (positive integer) quotients are just itself and $1$.

In fact, the [Jordan-Holder theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_series) states that every non-trivial finite group in some sense "factors" uniquely into simple groups (although "factors" isn't exactly the right term). In fact when you apply the Jordan-Holder theorem to the $\mathbb{Z}_n$ (integers mod $n$) groups, you'll recover the [fundamental theorem of arithmetic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_arithmetic). :)

*EDIT:* Note there is no need to assume $G$ is finite. Suppose $G$ is non-trivial has no non-trivial proper subgroups. Pick any non-identity element. This will generate a non-trivial subgroup. Since $G$ has no non-trivial proper subgroups, it must be generated by that element. Thus $G$ is cyclic. So either $G$ is isomorphic to the integers or integers mod some $n$. In the former case, we have many non-trivial proper subgroups (e.g., the even integers). Thus $G$ must be finite.

Comment: You can drop the "finite": the only nontrivial groups with no nontrivial proper subgroups are the finite cylic groups of prime order. Proof: pick $x\in G$, $x\neq e$. Then $\langle x\rangle = G$, so $G$ is cyclic. If $x^2=e$, then $|G|=2$; if $x^2\neq e$, then $\langle x^2\rangle=\langle x\rangle$ so $x$ has finite order, and you can proceed from there.

Comment: Thanks for catching that! I'll revert that edit back to my original post. :)